# Interactive PDF Reader: Android

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, android-ndk

I wanted to open internal anchors and embedded hyperlink from pdf viewer application. What would the suggested way to implement this functionality. As I can right now read pdf successfully.

Comment: Could you edit your question? It's unclear what you want to do and what you ask.

Comment: I wanted to open internal anchors and embedded hyperlink from pdf viewer application. What would the suggested way to implement this functionality. As I can right now read pdf successfully.

Comment: Now it's more clear. Update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MuPDF reader is not supporting interactive feature. But you can do one thing, you can create separate each PDF wise text file, in that you can mention x,y co-ordinates of interactive area. 
And you can map that area in PDF pagewise image, and make that part interactive. Hope you do understand.

Answer (score -2):

Simply you need to have Adobe Acrobat Reader.